# Split one cell data into two variables before save in csv

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I'm doing API web scraping in loop function and save all the bind in one file. The whole work will involve many files reproduction. I wish to split the Observation time (19th column) into date and hour, and I also want further read-plotting works able to recognize the date column in date format. Is it possible to do this before saving the CSV or I have to open back the CSV file to perform this?

```
startDate <- as.Date("01-11-14", format="%d-%m-%y")
endDate <- as.Date("31-01-15",format="%d-%m-%y")

days <- seq(startDate, endDate, "1 day")

lapply(days[1:92], function(day) {
  get_sounding_data(
region = "seasia",
date = day,
from_hr = "00",
to_hr = "00",
station_number = "48615")
}) -> soundings_48615

new_df <- map(soundings_48615, . %>% mutate_all(parse_guess))
str(new_df)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)
dat <- bind_rows(new_df)

write.csv(dat, 'c:/Users/Hp/Documents/yr/climatology/yr_SoundingIndexLowerPart/2014.csv')
get_sounding_data <- NULL
```

here how its look in csv..

```
    ... mixing ratio    temperature  Observation time   Precip.
  1         18.48           299.23        141102/0000    64.52
  2         17.28           298.81        141103/0000    59.4
  3         18.65           299.07        141104/0000    61.5
```

here is the data

```
str(new_df)
List of 8
 $ :'data.frame':   0 obs. of  0 variables
 $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  30 variables:
  ..$ 1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness              : num 5775
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number                     : num 3003
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV          : num 3325
  ..$ CAPE using virtual temperature             : num 1103
  ..$ CINS using virtual temperature             : num -22.1
  ..$ Convective Available Potential Energy      : num 996
  ..$ Convective Inhibition                      : num -31.3
  ..$ Cross totals index                         : num 20.9
  ..$ Equilibrum Level                           : num 151
  ..$ Equilibrum Level using virtual temperature : num 151
  ..$ K index                                    : num 38.7
  ..$ Level of Free Convection                   : num 822
  ..$ LFCT using virtual temperature             : num 833
  ..$ LIFT computed using virtual temperature    : num -3.05
  ..$ Lifted index                               : num -2.59
  ..$ Mean mixed layer mixing ratio              : num 18.5
  ..$ Mean mixed layer potential temperature     : num 299
  ..$ Observation time                           : chr "141102/0000"
  ..$ Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: num 64.5
  ..$ Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: num 961
  ..$ Showalter index                            : num -0.9
  ..$ Station elevation                          : num 5
  ..$ Station identifier                         : chr "WMKC"
  ..$ Station latitude                           : num 6.16
  ..$ Station longitude                          : num 102
  ..$ Station number                             : int 48615
  ..$ SWEAT index                                : num 211
  ..$ Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level  : num 296
  ..$ Totals totals index                        : num 44.6
  ..$ Vertical totals index                      : num 23.7
 $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  30 variables:
  ..$ 1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness              : num 5771
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number                     : num 328
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV          : num 395
  ..$ CAPE using virtual temperature             : num 502
  ..$ CINS using virtual temperature             : num -55.3
  ..$ Convective Available Potential Energy      : num 417
  ..$ Convective Inhibition                      : num -61.7
  ..$ Cross totals index                         : num 21.1
  ..$ Equilibrum Level                           : num 167
  ..$ Equilibrum Level using virtual temperature : num 167
  ..$ K index                                    : num 35.1
  ..$ Level of Free Convection                   : num 826
  ..$ LFCT using virtual temperature             : num 835
  ..$ LIFT computed using virtual temperature    : num -2.38
  ..$ Lifted index                               : num -1.98
  ..$ Mean mixed layer mixing ratio              : num 17.3
  ..$ Mean mixed layer potential temperature     : num 299
  ..$ Observation time                           : chr "141103/0000"
  ..$ Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: num 59.4
  ..$ Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: num 952
  ..$ Showalter index                            : num -0.65
  ..$ Station elevation                          : num 5
  ..$ Station identifier                         : chr "WMKC"
  ..$ Station latitude                           : num 6.16
  ..$ Station longitude                          : num 102
  ..$ Station number                             : int 48615
  ..$ SWEAT index                                : num 212
  ..$ Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level  : num 295
  ..$ Totals totals index                        : num 44.6
  ..$ Vertical totals index                      : num 23.5
 $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  30 variables:
  ..$ 1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness              : num 5775
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number                     : num 431
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV          : num 480
  ..$ CAPE using virtual temperature             : num 1354
  ..$ CINS using virtual temperature             : num -8.6
  ..$ Convective Available Potential Energy      : num 1217
  ..$ Convective Inhibition                      : num -11.3
  ..$ Cross totals index                         : num 21.7
  ..$ Equilibrum Level                           : num 142
  ..$ Equilibrum Level using virtual temperature : num 142
  ..$ K index                                    : num 37.4
  ..$ Level of Free Convection                   : num 888
  ..$ LFCT using virtual temperature             : num 896
  ..$ LIFT computed using virtual temperature    : num -3.67
  ..$ Lifted index                               : num -3.3
  ..$ Mean mixed layer mixing ratio              : num 18.6
  ..$ Mean mixed layer potential temperature     : num 299
  ..$ Observation time                           : chr "141104/0000"
  ..$ Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: num 61.5
  ..$ Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: num 966
  ..$ Showalter index                            : num -0.97
  ..$ Station elevation                          : num 5
  ..$ Station identifier                         : chr "WMKC"
  ..$ Station latitude                           : num 6.16
  ..$ Station longitude                          : num 102
  ..$ Station number                             : int 48615
  ..$ SWEAT index                                : num 226
  ..$ Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level  : num 296
  ..$ Totals totals index                        : num 44.4
  ..$ Vertical totals index                      : num 22.7
 $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  30 variables:
  ..$ 1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness              : num 5771
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number                     : num 215
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV          : num 236
  ..$ CAPE using virtual temperature             : num 910
  ..$ CINS using virtual temperature             : num -37.2
  ..$ Convective Available Potential Energy      : num 829
  ..$ Convective Inhibition                      : num -43.9
  ..$ Cross totals index                         : num 21.9
  ..$ Equilibrum Level                           : num 168
  ..$ Equilibrum Level using virtual temperature : num 167
  ..$ K index                                    : num 39.7
  ..$ Level of Free Convection                   : num 829
  ..$ LFCT using virtual temperature             : num 842
  ..$ LIFT computed using virtual temperature    : num -2.68
  ..$ Lifted index                               : num -2.43
  ..$ Mean mixed layer mixing ratio              : num 18
  ..$ Mean mixed layer potential temperature     : num 299
  ..$ Observation time                           : chr "141105/0000"
  ..$ Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: num 64.9
  ..$ Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: num 963
  ..$ Showalter index                            : num -1.45
  ..$ Station elevation                          : num 5
  ..$ Station identifier                         : chr "WMKC"
  ..$ Station latitude                           : num 6.16
  ..$ Station longitude                          : num 102
  ..$ Station number                             : int 48615
  ..$ SWEAT index                                : num 229
  ..$ Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level  : num 295
  ..$ Totals totals index                        : num 45.2
  ..$ Vertical totals index                      : num 23.3
 $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  30 variables:
  ..$ 1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness              : num 5757
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number                     : num 59
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV          : num 70.8
  ..$ CAPE using virtual temperature             : num 546
  ..$ CINS using virtual temperature             : num -51.5
  ..$ Convective Available Potential Energy      : num 455
  ..$ Convective Inhibition                      : num -64.1
  ..$ Cross totals index                         : num 20
  ..$ Equilibrum Level                           : num 194
  ..$ Equilibrum Level using virtual temperature : num 193
  ..$ K index                                    : num 35.3
  ..$ Level of Free Convection                   : num 808
  ..$ LFCT using virtual temperature             : num 834
  ..$ LIFT computed using virtual temperature    : num -2.24
  ..$ Lifted index                               : num -2.04
  ..$ Mean mixed layer mixing ratio              : num 17.3
  ..$ Mean mixed layer potential temperature     : num 299
  ..$ Observation time                           : chr "141106/0000"
  ..$ Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: num 59.6
  ..$ Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: num 949
  ..$ Showalter index                            : num 0.42
  ..$ Station elevation                          : num 5
  ..$ Station identifier                         : chr "WMKC"
  ..$ Station latitude                           : num 6.16
  ..$ Station longitude                          : num 102
  ..$ Station number                             : int 48615
  ..$ SWEAT index                                : num 201
  ..$ Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level  : num 295
  ..$ Totals totals index                        : num 43.5
  ..$ Vertical totals index                      : num 23.5
 $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  30 variables:
  ..$ 1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness              : num 5777
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number                     : num 80.3
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV          : num 86.5
  ..$ CAPE using virtual temperature             : num 1149
  ..$ CINS using virtual temperature             : num -9.57
  ..$ Convective Available Potential Energy      : num 1067
  ..$ Convective Inhibition                      : num -12.4
  ..$ Cross totals index                         : num 21.6
  ..$ Equilibrum Level                           : num 143
  ..$ Equilibrum Level using virtual temperature : num 142
  ..$ K index                                    : num 38.6
  ..$ Level of Free Convection                   : num 845
  ..$ LFCT using virtual temperature             : num 901
  ..$ LIFT computed using virtual temperature    : num -3.03
  ..$ Lifted index                               : num -2.79
  ..$ Mean mixed layer mixing ratio              : num 18.3
  ..$ Mean mixed layer potential temperature     : num 299
  ..$ Observation time                           : chr "141107/0000"
  ..$ Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: num 66
  ..$ Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: num 965
  ..$ Showalter index                            : num -1.15
  ..$ Station elevation                          : num 5
  ..$ Station identifier                         : chr "WMKC"
  ..$ Station latitude                           : num 6.16
  ..$ Station longitude                          : num 102
  ..$ Station number                             : int 48615
  ..$ SWEAT index                                : num 239
  ..$ Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level  : num 296
  ..$ Totals totals index                        : num 44.9
  ..$ Vertical totals index                      : num 23.3
 $ :Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1 obs. of  30 variables:
  ..$ 1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness              : num 5775
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number                     : num 29.1
  ..$ Bulk Richardson Number using CAPV          : num 32.7
  ..$ CAPE using virtual temperature             : num 503
  ..$ CINS using virtual temperature             : num -5.45
  ..$ Convective Available Potential Energy      : num 447
  ..$ Convective Inhibition                      : num -8.42
  ..$ Cross totals index                         : num 20.8
  ..$ Equilibrum Level                           : num 197
  ..$ Equilibrum Level using virtual temperature : num 197
  ..$ K index                                    : num 35.7
  ..$ Level of Free Convection                   : num 871
  ..$ LFCT using virtual temperature             : num 875
  ..$ LIFT computed using virtual temperature    : num -1.07
  ..$ Lifted index                               : num -0.9
  ..$ Mean mixed layer mixing ratio              : num 17.7
  ..$ Mean mixed layer potential temperature     : num 298
  ..$ Observation time                           : chr "141108/0000"
  ..$ Precipitable water [mm] for entire sounding: num 65.8
  ..$ Pres [hPa] of the Lifted Condensation Level: num 966
  ..$ Showalter index                            : num 0.29
  ..$ Station elevation                          : num 5
  ..$ Station identifier                         : chr "WMKC"
  ..$ Station latitude                           : num 6.16
  ..$ Station longitude                          : num 102
  ..$ Station number                             : int 48615
  ..$ SWEAT index                                : num 242
  ..$ Temp [K] of the Lifted Condensation Level  : num 295
  ..$ Totals totals index                        : num 41.7
  ..$ Vertical totals index                      : num 20.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use `tidy`'s `seperate` to split a column into segments of an original one:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  `Observation time` = c(
    '141102/0000',
    '141103/0000',
    '141104/0000'
  )
)

df %>% separate(
  col = `Observation time`,
  into = c('Date', 'Time'),
  sep = '/'
)
```

This outputs:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Date   Time 
  <chr>  <chr>
1 141102 0000 
2 141103 0000 
3 141104 0000
```

Note that the `Observation time` column is dropped and replaced by `Date` and `Time`. If you want, you can convert them back to integer (or something else) via a `mutate`.

Comment: I'm updating my question to add the clarity. Can I just pass the dat$'Observation time' without manually key in the observation time and separate it from there?

Comment: Attaching my web scrape code might scares others, so I edit again to included some data. Hope it will be helpfull

Comment: It should be write before the `write.csv (dat, 'c/Users/..` right?  I tried but its not working..

Comment: Too much red line warning make me overlooked the new error. It just typing error anyway. Your suggested code works, it just the matter of 'into', not 'to'. My bad for simply copying.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

to save it into date and time, first you need to understand in what format is the date and time variables stored in (Julian time, roman ... etc). Then, we need to split them into 2 columns with something like:

```
library(tidyr)
separate(data = df, col = 'Observation Time', into = c("Date","Time"), sep = "/")
```